# Why must class member function types be called with invoke?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun test() {
    class Test(val foo: ((Double, Double) -> Double)?)
    val test = Test(null)

    if(test.foo != null) test.foo(1.0, 2.0)
}
```

The code above generates the error:

> Kotlin: Reference has a nullable type '((Double, Double) ->
>   DoubleArray)?', use explicit '?.invoke()' to make a function-like call
>   instead.

If I follow the errors advice and change the call to `test.foo?.invoke(1.0, 2.0)`, the code compiles but IntelliJ now reports

> Unnecessary safe call on a non-null receiver of type '((Double, Double) -> DoubleArray)

Following that advice, I end up with `test.foo.invoke(1.0, 2.0)` which I thought was interchangeable with `test.foo(1.0, 2.0)`; why is that not the case here?

When foo is not a class member, things work as I would expect:

```
fun test2() {
    val foo: ((Double, Double) -> Double)? = null

    if(foo != null) foo(1.0, 2.0)
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. You could create an issue on http://kotl.in/issue if it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open issue for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4113

Currently, it's target version is 1.3.

Comment: Good find! Didn't turn up in my initial searches.

Comment: It some digging before I found it. Thanks for confirming it was a bug and not just some Kotlin quirk!

Comment: Too bad it's been 8 years since that issue was created, and it's still open.

Answer (score 2):

The [smart casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#checking-for-null-in-conditions) does not seem to be working correctly in this situation, I'd expect the same as you did. It works only with `invoke()`:

[image]

My **workaround** would be using `let` instead:

```
test.foo?.let { foo ->
    foo(1.0, 2.0)
}
```